# why does re.sub replaces none of the occurrences even there is already pattern, repl and string added

Tags: python, python-re

a.txt is a file with this string:

```
g g abc
abc
457625

er
```

```
oldstring = "abc"
newstring = "def"
with open('a.txt', 'r') as f:
       data = f.read()
       re.sub(r"\b{}\b".format(oldstring), r"\b{}\b".format(newstring), data)
with open('b.txt', 'w') as out:
       out.write(data)
```

With this python code, I thought I can end up having b.txt where I can have "abc" turned to "def". Surprisingly, I get the exact same string I have in a.txt.

Can anyone tell me where is the error in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the output of the `re.sub` back to the original variable.

```py
   data = re.sub(r"\b{}\b".format(oldstring), newstring, data)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, sorry that I failed to find out this careless mistake. May I also ask here another question:

If I have "abcdefg". how can I turn it to "defdefg"? I know the code I have now forces "abc" to have space char in front and after, because of the "\b", but I want to include both cases. Is there a way?

Comment: You used `\b` in your regular expression. That means word boundaries, including punctuation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by both cases. I mean, the expression with \b is a subset of without, right? Might want to explain how you want the replacement to happen.

Comment: Thank you first, because I solved the problem.

What I mean is actually replacing both "abc" in "abcefg" and "a abc c". The solution is only not to use \b in the regex, because as you said, \b means boundaries. Hence, it should be r"{}".format(string)

Comment: @desmond although if you think about it `r"{}".format(string)` is just the same as just `string`.

Comment: I read through the documentation and you are right.